# Adding all fields from a Map value to Json in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a list of documents, with data in the form of `Map[String, Any]` so that it can be added to a json object with fields and values respectively. So my code looks something like this when parsing:

```
val JsonDoc = Json.obj(
      "ORFID" -> doc("ORFID").toString,
      "ORF_len" -> doc("ORF_len").toString,
      "start" -> doc("start").toString,
      "end" -> doc("end").toString
...// more fields
)
```

However some documents may be missing one of the fields, so I need a more dynamic approach depending on each documents fields, or else an exception is thrown. What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Having `Any` as value type of the `Map` is not a very good idea

Answer (score 2):

You could try [JsObject](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsObject.html) instead. Its constructor needs a Seq of tuples which you can get from your map with the method `toSeq`, this assuming, you want to use the same keys in your json as in the Map.

```
val jsonDoc = new JsonObj(doc.toSeq)
```

Comment: unfortunately, its a map of (String, Any) and the required typing is (String, JsValue), I resorted to use getOrElse on the fields that could potentially by empty to avoid the error